# Java.lang disappeared from Java

Tags: java

I don't really have an idea what I'm doing but I used to be able to run some code from a textbook.
Whenever I try not I get an error cannot find symbol because of Double.parseDouble...
How... did java.lang just go missing and how can I fix it?

Comment: Without seeing the actual error, your Java installation might be corrupt. Re-install.

Comment: Do you have a class or field of your own called `Double`?

Comment: maybe you can provide some more information about your use case - where do you run it from, maybe some code, the exact exception?!

Comment: Ahp!! There it is! Aw dammit. Gone again.

Comment: If you're using eclipse or some other IDE, perhaps java has been upgraded and the old version removed, and you didn't update the IDE settings to point to the new installation.